# Unable to deploy Flask app to Elastic Beanstalk without 500 errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, mod-wsgi, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've pushed my Flask app to ElasticBeanstalk but am getting 500 errors on every page and `Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.` showing up in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

Here's the full stacktrace in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815358 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0] mod_wsgi (pid=21701): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815389 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0] mod_wsgi (pid=21701): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815410 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815435 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 5, in <module>
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815466 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0]     from charts import *
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815478 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/charts.py", line 6, in <module>
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815494 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0]     from scipy.stats import linregress
[Wed Mar 18 22:02:36.815514 2015] [:error] [pid 21701] [remote 50.23.**2.10:0] ImportError: No module named scipy.stats
```

Here's what the first portion of my `application.py` looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import os
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler
from charts import *

application = app = Flask(__name__)
```

I'm assigning my flask app to the `application` object, which is all the docs say I need to do. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The error says that it can't import `scipy.stats`. Is scipy installed?

Comment: But is it installed into the same Python installation that mod_wsgi was compiled against? Or have you if using a Python virtual environment setup things so that virtual environment is used.